# $.Ajax call not executing XMLHttpRequest?

Tags: jquery, ajax

The following code isn't making any AJAX call (Nothing appears on Firebug's console)

```
<SCRIPT type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.8.3.js"></SCRIPT>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
  alert( "hola" );
  $.ajax({
    url: "index.php?action=ajaxMenu&sa=get",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function(data, status, xhttp) {
      if ( data ) { alert ('Got Data'); } else { alert('No Data'); }
    }
  })
})
</script>
```

The first alert gets executed.

However, if I manually enter into the url, I get the following response:

```
{"data":[{"id":"3","name":"Menu 1"},{"id":"4","name":"menu2"}]}
```

Gotta be something simple, I think.

Thanks!!

Comment: Try using `console.log` instead of `alert`s. Firefox has some weird behavior concerning the latter

Comment: are both of your pages in the same folder? And are you opening the file through the `file:///` scheme or using a server such as apache?

Comment: Does your network tab show the ajax request being fired?

Comment: @FabrícioMatté Yes, it was simple, I was accesing through file:///, thats why it wasn't getting executed. Thanks!! Put as answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Chrome won't allow you to execute XHR requests through the `file:///` for security reasons. Use a local server such as WAMP, EasyPHP or XAMPP for testing `=]`.

An workaround that is possible with Chrome is to start it from command line with this option:

> --allow-file-access-from-files

But honestly, you'd end up running into other security restrictions sooner or later, hence using a local server is the way to go.

Comment: I have firefox, seems that isn't allowed neither. Thanks!

Comment: Weird, it was allowed in FF a couple versions back. I guess they fixed that for security as well.